# How to define more than 10 containers in one Dockerrun.aws.json?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am working on application where I use Multi-container Docker Elastic Beanstalk. I have one Dockerrun.aws.json where I define 10 containers. The problem is that I need more than 10 containers on my instance, but AWS allow only 10 container task definition in one Dockerrun.aws.json. In addition, I need to use Elastic Beanstalk because that's how I deploy the new code to the containers. Can you give be advise the best approach for my problem.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The way that I did it was to create a new Multi-container Docker Elastic Beanstalk Application with it's own Dockerrun.aws.json that had the extra containers. 
The containers in the two elastic beanstalk(the one with 10 containers and the one with the extra ones) communicate with each other via HTTP.